# Calculate distance between two point in miles in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, distance

I have two points example

```
point1 = {lat: 40.6974034,
        lng: -74.1197636}
point2 = {lat: 42.694034,
        lng: -75.117636}
```

I want to calculate distance between these two points in miles unit in NextJs.
Can anyone suggest me any package which I can use?

Comment: From [help/on-topic] - _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._.  So unfortunately this question is off-topic for the site.  You could seek help writing a solution here, or use https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to request help finding packages that would assist you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```js
const point1 = {
    lat: 40.6974034,
    lng: -74.1197636
};
const point2 = {
    lat: 42.694034,
    lng: -75.117636
};


const getDistance = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) => {
    if ((lat1 === lat2) && (lon1 === lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }
  const radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
  const radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
  const theta = lon1-lon2;
  const radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
  let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  if (dist > 1) {
    dist = 1;
  }
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit === "K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 };
  if (unit === "N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 };
  return dist;
};

console.log('Miles', getDistance(point1.lat, point1.lng, point2.lat, point2.lng,'M'));

console.log('Kilometers', getDistance(point1.lat, point1.lng, point2.lat, point2.lng,'K'));

console.log('Nautical miles', getDistance(point1.lat, point1.lng, point2.lat, point2.lng,'N'));
```

I think you can use this function, you can also pass different unit, N from nautical miles, M from miles and K from Kilometers.